# Firefox crashes when I try to add comment!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, firefox

I am experiencing a very strange problems. Whenever I try to add comment to an answer Firefox crashes and Crash reporter shows up. It does not happen always but at certain question/answers whenever I try to do so it crashes.

Anyone who faces the sme problem?

Sorry cant add comments due to the same bug..

@Kenny - Like this one and many others.

Comment: No, mine is insane (no repro btw)

Comment: Which question?

Comment: I am also unable to post a comment...Oh, wait... `:P`

Comment: Could you try it again with a clean profile? @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson: That was cruel. ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this.

Start Firefox in "safe mode" (all extensions disabled) and try again.